# Normalizing vectors to be the same size to retain PSD data

Tags: matlab, power-spectral-density, spectrogram, periodogram

**Context**: 
`PSD=periodogram(y)` in MATLAB gives the PSD (power spectral density) estimate of a sound-source signal. I want to find the local maximum within 3 different x ranges of `PSD`.

**How do I make a vector that maps 1:1 to the PSD -y value vector?**[image]
The x values that MATLAB generates are Hz - frequency values, so I don't want to change the values per se, but create a vector that goes from `x=0:3500`, but have the same number of elements as the PSD vector, `PSD= 32769*1 double`.

How do I do this while retaining the same data?
    **PSD plot. acquired with plot(PSD) <-- x values generated by MATLAB**

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiYGB.png

    %% formantdaddy will try to do all the steps of the process
% 1. grab sound from folder
% 2. get PSD = Power Spectral Density
% 3. look for local maxima within prefined ranges 
    % 200 - 800 Hz
    % 800 - 1800 Hz
    % 1800 - 3500 Hz
%store data into a struct

clear all;
close all;
clc;
%% audioread .wav file
[y Fs]= audioread('100-daddy1.wav');
%% y=source signal
sourceFig=figure(1);
plot(y);
xlabel('milliseconds'); ylabel('amplitude'); title('spectrogram = voice source signal');

%% PSD - Power Spectral Density <-- peaks here should give formants
filterfcn=figure(2);
PSD=periodogram(y); %calculate the power spectral density of the source signal
plot(PSD);
ylabel('magnitude || intensity of signal'); xlabel('frequency in Hz'); title('PSD of Source');
xlim([0, .35*10^4]);
%% F1 range  
subset1=zeros(1, 601); %create a vector to store PSD values within the range of interest
for x=200:800;
    subset1(x)=PSD(x);% input in the values of interest
end

for x=200:800;
    Y_max=max(subset1);
    F1=x;
end
disp(F1);
disp(Y_max);
% find the max value within the range
%PROBLEM: wanted to find the x value which corresponded to the max y <-- but this actually is the max y value
%PROBLEM: x vector not the same size as PSD values within the range, so many points not considered. 

%% F2 range
subset2=zeros(1, 1001);
for x=800:1800;
    subset2(x)=PSD(x);
end

for x=800:1800;
    Y2_max=max(subset2);
    F2=x;
end
disp(F2);
disp(Y2_max);
%% F3 range
subset3=zeros(1, 1701);
for x=1800:3500;
    subset3(x)=PSD(x);
end
for x=1800:3500;
    Y3_max=max(subset2);
    F3=x;
end
disp(F3);
disp(Y3_max);
%% store values into a struct
Ftable=struct("FileName", "100-daddy1.wav", "F1_Hz", F1, "F2_Hz", F2, "F3_Hz", F3);
```

Comment: keep getting errors with the [pxx,f] = periodogram(_,fs) version of the call. https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/periodogram.html

Answer (score 1):

For function call **[pxx, f] = periodogram(y_soundsource_data,window,nfft, Fs);**
  you can get the pxx = PSD points= vector of y values, and f= frequency points tied 1:1 to the pxx values.

... this requires that you specify nfft & Fs

1. You can get y_soundsource_data and Fs<-- sampling frequency, from the audioread function. `file[y Fs]= audioread('100-daddy1.wav');`
2. window and nfft are not understood by the periodogram function UNLESS you define them.

   - **y_soundsource_data** and **Fs** are understood, because audioread returns the data metrics.
   - **nfft** - refers to the number of points used in the DFT. A larger nfft value will lead to a better estimation. nfft MUST be an integer. You can't have half a point.
   - **window** = vector of the size of the y_soundsource_data. 1:length_y_soundsource_data
   - both **window** and **nfft** need to be defined before you call the periodogram function.

   [image: code]

[image: variable data-types and sizes]

[image: plot figure(4)]

[image: followup]
keep getting errors with the [pxx,f] = periodogram(_,fs) version of the call. mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/periodogram.html

Comment: keep getting errors with the [pxx,f] = periodogram(_,fs) version of the call. https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/periodogram.html